# How core data works different from sqlite functionally?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data

If I am having 1000 records in a database and I have to find a common name from that records.

Then what exactly will be the internal implementation for sqlite and core data base?
I mean I know the query for both condition but what happened in the internal level that makes core data more optimised than sqlite?

Comment: who says that core data is more "optimised" than sqlite? what does optimised even mean here?

Comment: @nburk In the core data documentation they were saying that core data is much faster than sqlite and its memory footprint is much less than sqlite. That's why I want to know what exactly will happen in the question which I posted?

Comment: can you post a link to that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html

Comment: that link doesn't contain such a statement... maybe it was one of its subpages?

Comment: yes,Please read all the document and you will able to find out everything about core data and then let m know what difference is in my above query?

Comment: can you tell me the exact quote or where i can find it?